# how to create swipe controls in corona

Tags: unity-game-engine, coronasdk, swipe

I am trying to create a game with Corona, but I can't figure out how to make swipe controls. I want to make a character that can move along x, -x, y, -y depending on which direction you swipe. any advice is needed because I'm lost. This code currently uses buttons to move the player when the button is press the player moves in that direction. I would like to change the button press to a swipe. The move events are at the bottom, and the button press events are in the middle.

```
local backdrop = display.setDefault("background", 1, 1, 1)

local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()

local square = display.newRect( 0, 0, 5, 5 )
--print(square)

_W = display.contentWidth; -- Get the width of the screen
_H = display.contentHeight; -- Get the height of the screen

motionDown = 0;
motionUp = 0;
motionRight = 0;
motionLeft = 0;
motionSquare = 5

speed = 4

local left = display.newRect(0,0,_W/2,_H/1.19)
    left.x = _W/4.5; left.y = _H/2;

local right = display.newRect(0,0,_W/2,_H/1.19)
    right.x = _W/1.25; right.y = _H/2;

local top = display.newRect(0,0,_W,_H/5.5)
    top.x = _W/2; top.y =0;

local bottem = display.newRect(0,0,_W,_H/5.5)
    bottem.x = _W/2; bottem.y =_H;

    player = display.newImage("player.png", display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY)
        player.x = math.random(10,_W-10)
        player.y = math.random(10,_H-10)

    player:toFront(player)

    physics.addBody( player, "static" )


    function left:tap()   --Left
            motionDown = 0;
            motionUp = 0;
            motionRight = 0;
            motionLeft = -speed;

            local square = display.newRect( 0, 0, 5, 5 )
            square.strokeWidth = 3
            square:setFillColor( 0 )
            square:setStrokeColor( 0, 0, 0 )
            square.x = player.x + 10 ; square.y = player.y;

            local function moveSquare (event)
                square.x = square.x + motionSquare;
                end
                Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", moveSquare)
        return square
    end
        left:addEventListener("tap",left) 

        square = left:tap()

    function right:tap()      --Right
            motionDown = 0;
            motionUp = 0;
            motionLeft = 0;
            motionRight = speed;

            local square = display.newRect( 0, 0, 5, 5 )
            square.strokeWidth = 3
            square:setFillColor( 0 )
            square:setStrokeColor( 0, 0, 0 )
            square.x = player.x - 10 ; square.y = player.y;

            local function moveSquare (event)
                square.x = square.x - motionSquare;
                end
                Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", moveSquare)
        return square
    end
        right:addEventListener("tap",right) 

        square = right:tap()

    function top:tap()          --Top
            motionDown = 0;
            motionRight = 0;
            motionLeft = 0;
            motionUp = -speed;
            local left = display.newRect(0,0,5,5)

            local square = display.newRect( 0, 0, 5, 5 )
            square.strokeWidth = 3
            square:setFillColor( 0 )
            square:setStrokeColor( 0, 0, 0 )
            square.x = player.x ; square.y = player.y + 10;

            local function moveSquare (event)
                square.y = square.y + motionSquare;
                end
                Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", moveSquare)
        return square
    end
        top:addEventListener("tap",top) 

        square = top:tap()

    function bottem:tap(event) --Bottem
            motionRight = 0;
            motionUp = 0;
            motionLeft = 0;
            motionDown = speed;

            local square = display.newRect( 0, 0, 5, 5 )
            square.strokeWidth = 3
            square:setFillColor( 0 )
            square:setStrokeColor( 0, 0, 0 )
            square.x = player.x ; square.y = player.y - 10;

            local function moveSquare (event)
            square.y = square.y - motionSquare;
            end
            Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", moveSquare)
        return square
    end

        bottem:addEventListener("tap",bottem) 

        square = bottem:tap()

   -- Move character
    local function movePlayer (event)
            player.x = player.x + motionRight;
            if player.x > display.contentWidth then  player.x = 0 
            end
        end
        Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", movePlayer)

    local function movePlayer (event)
        player.x = player.x + motionLeft;
            if player.x < 0 then player.x = display.contentWidth
            end
        end
        Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", movePlayer)

    local function movePlayer (event)
        player.y = player.y + motionUp;
            if player.y > display.contentHeight then player.y = 0
            end
        end
        Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", movePlayer)

    local function movePlayer (event)
        player.y = player.y + motionDown;
            if player.y < 0 then player.y = display.contentHeight
            end
        end
        Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", movePlayer)

        local function moveSquare (event)
            square.y = square.y + motionSquare;
                if player.y < 0 then player.y = display.contentHeight
                end
            end
            Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", moveSquare)
```

Comment: Read [Best way to detect swipe in 4 directions](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/62284-best-way-to-detect-swipe-in-4-directions/) or [How to move a character left and right with Corona SDK](http://www.gamebuildingtools.com/corona-sdk/move-character-left-right-corona-sdk/). You can find more infromation using Google search.

Comment: I had already read both of those and neither of them gets me to the point that I want. the first one doesn't move a character, and the second one creates buttons to move the character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you already find a solution for this? I already answered a similar question before, I will use the same example:

```
local function globalTouchHandler(event)

    local swipeLength = math.abs(event.x - event.xStart) 
    print(event.phase, swipeLength)

    local t = event.target
    local phase = event.phase

    if (phase == "began") then

    elseif (phase == "moved") then

    elseif (phase == "ended" or phase == "cancelled") then

        if (event.xStart > event.x and swipeLength > 50) then 
            -- left
        elseif (event.xStart < event.x and swipeLength > 50) then 
            -- right
        end 
        if (event.y < event.yStart and swipeLength > 50) then
            -- up
        end
    end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch",globalTouchHandler)
```

Comment: Ok, I'm fairly new to coding, and I understand all of the basics, but how do I implement that into my code. because I don't see the object that is being moved in this code. I added my code into the main post if that will help you explain it to me.

Comment: It's depending on what you are trying to do, for example, just below this line: "-- left"   you can add this code player.x = player.x - 5;